# Node.js - installing johnny five library on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, johnny-five

I'm trying to install the johnny five library for Node.js on windows 7  but keep getting an error:

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.15 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\User>npm install johnny-five
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/firmata
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-collections
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/descriptor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/compulsive
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/serialport
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/temporal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/firmata
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-collections
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/descriptor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/compulsive
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serialport
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/temporal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.18
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sf/0.1.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.
16.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.18
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sf/0.1.6

> serialport@1.1.3 install C:\Users\User\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules
\serialport
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\User\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport>node "C:\Progra
m Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bi
n\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: ImportError: No module named site
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:
5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.
16.tgz
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I had the same problem on mac, but solved it by installing xcode command line components as suggested in a previous post, but don't know how to solve this for windows.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

(this is much the same as Owen's answer really, just with a couple of gotchas added in - but I can't comment yet, so...)

I've just got this working on Windows 8 but suspect much of it will apply to Win7 too:

- check you have python installed **and** included in your PATH environmental variable - "python --version" in cmd should return "Python 2.7.5" (3.x won't work)
- Install Visual Studio Express - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express
- Install Windows SDK - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904949
- remember to open a fresh instance of cmd.exe (I'm using the nodejs-specific one, in case that makes a difference) after doing all this, it usually won't pick up environmental changes

For the arduino itself, remember to check the drivers (http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/windows) and I had to feed the com port to Johnny Five (https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/board-with-port.md).

Comment: For posterity: I've received the OP's error messages (amongst other subsequent errors) when trying to install `topojson` (`npm install -g topojson --msvs_version=2013`). I've installed Visual Studio Express 2013 and Windows SDK, as well as `npm install -g gyp`, but continue to receive the errors, which begin with `gyp ERR! configure error` and `gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: ImportError: No module named site`.

Comment: It turns out that `No module named site` probably indicates a problem with the Python path. I had `PYTHONPATH`, `PYTHONHOME`, and `Path` system environment variables [set appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5687052/489704), but perhaps I should have been using `npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7` as outlined [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp). Instead, I removed `PYTHONPATH` & `PYTHONHOME`, and removed Python from `Path`, then reinstalled Python 2.7.6 (my existing install was courtesy of ArcGIS), and this error is now bypassed while others have emerged.

Comment: My new errors began with `gyp ERR! build error` and `gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1`. I uninstalled MS Visual Studio Express 2013 and installed MSVS Express 2012, and `topojson` has now installed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

OK i had a Similar problem in Windows . You have to install visual studio 2012/2010 . I had Vs2012 installed So i ran the npm command with the switch

```
npm install johnny-five --msvs_version=2012
```

Which solved the problem for me. Basically serialport package in johnny five need to rebuild itself for the operating system so it needs the run the nodegyp package which will look for MSBuild

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your specific error but I had a lot of different node-gyp related errors with npm install on windows until I uninstalled all Visual Studio products and followed the instructions on https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp to a T. That includes specifically Visual Studio 2010 (not 2012 which didn't work), the SDK, and the SDK update. After I followed those steps exactly I stopped getting errors (including a successful test installation of Johnny Five a few minutes ago. Maybe worth a try if you haven't followed these steps already.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the required software to run `node-gyp`:

- https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

You can configure version of Visual Studio used by `gyp` via an environment variable so you can avoid having to set the `--msvs_version=2012` property.

Examples:

- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2012` for Visual Studio 2012
- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013e` (the 'e' stands for 'express edition')

For the full list see 
 - https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.29/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py#L209-294

This is still painful for Windows users of NodeJS as it assumes you have a copy of Python and Visual Studio installed and many end users will never have this. So I'm lobbying Joyent to the encourage them to include web sockets as part of CORE node and also to possible ship a GNU gcc compiler as part of NodeJS install so we can permanently fix this problem.

Feel free to add your vote at:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8005#issuecomment-50545326