# Vim shows: ImportError: No module named site. while I am using Canopy1.1

Tags: python, vim, enthought

I have installed Canopy 1.1 express in Windows Xp 32, and I use vim as editor. When I typing `:python print("hello")` in command line of vim ,it shows: `Importerror: No module named site`  and crashed.
In fact, my vim cannot load and plugin written by python(such as jedi-vim), and cannot execute any statements written in python.

I have set the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH as " [User Python Environment](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment) ", and have read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site) in stackoverflow.
In fact, I can use python, it works well. If I remove Canopy and use python 2.7 from Python Official, vim works well too. That means the environment of the system is right, and vim is right.

I think there must be something wrong between vim and canopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've just dealt with a very similar issue here: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/207

It's OS X and not Windows, but I think the issue is the same one. You probably need to change `sys.path` or `$PYTHONPATH` somehow. I don't know why this is an issue with canopy or vim.

Answer (score 0):

please check existence of `site` directory

Hint: `python` version below `2.7` does not have the `jedi-vim` support, so better disable jedi-vim
and try

If the problem still persisting remove your existing python and try re-installing it