# ImportError: No module named site VIM and Enthought canopy

Tags: python, vim, enthought, canopy

I was using vim and python perfectly fine till I upgrade to Maverick. Now I have a similar issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089654/vim-shows-importerror-no-module-named-site-while-i-am-using-canopy1-1). When I remove remove canopy path from `bash_profile` and use default python path , vim works fine, otherwise I am getting the above error. You can also see me report on jedi-vim [here](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/207#issuecomment-27162707)

UPDATE:
Also it seems my default python path is no longer in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Mavericks has a lot of issues I hear.

Comment: If it works without canopy and doesn't with canopy the problem seems to be on canopy's side and you should report to enthought... or give us more information if you really want some help.

Comment: @romainl I have already reported it to them. What kind of info do you need. You can find all my vim setting on jedi-vim link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone encountering this issue I resolved the problem by putting these lines into `.profile`:

```
export PYTHONDIR=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/mj/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.1.1189.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Now it works fine. In this way I can manage my python module with `canopy` and use default python. 
NOTE: I don't feel this is the best solution but at least solved my problem after 8h.

Answer (score 0):

please check existence of `site` directory under

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

Hint: `python` version below `2.7` does not have the `jedi-vim` support, so better disable jedi-vim
and try

If the problem still persisting remove your existing python and try re-installing it

even though your default python is `/usr/bin/python` you can specify at the start of your file

```
`#! /usr/bin/python2.7`

$ ls /usr/bin/py
python3   python3.3   python   python2   python2.7
....
```