# unable to edit .py files in vim after Mavericks OS upgrade

Tags: python, vim, enthought, osx-mavericks, canopy

I' ve recently installed Mavericks OS X.
Since then I am unable to manipulate a .py file using vim.
I can use `vi some_filename` as usual, but when I run `vi some_filename.py` I get the following error in the terminal:

```
"some_filename" [New File]ImportError: No module named site.
```

The weirdest thing is that the next line (Prompt) is intended far to the right, nothing of what I am typing is visible and after I press the return key the next prompt is intended even further to the right of the screen.

I use Canopy distribution as my default Python environment so maybe the issue has something to do with this fact

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this thread and see if it helps...
[ImportError: No module named site VIM and Enthought canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617936/importerror-no-module-named-site-vim-and-enthought-canopy)

You may also be interested in this knowledge base article about Mavericks-Python-Canopy:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22861925-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks-Python-Canopy

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today on Mavericks, reinstall the MacVim solved it.

```
brew reinstall macvim
```