# python does not work

Tags: python, windows, installation, windows-xp

I always downloaded python from python.org and install it on Windows machines (XP and 8 ) easily. On this Windows XP machine however I have the following problem.  After installing python2.7  32 bit on the machine , I cannot start neither the interactive python page nor the python shell ( IDLE or GUI ) ( neither form the Windows Start nor from the command line). I set the path in Windows ( and I double checked and renewed the  command line shell as well). From the Windows command line when I type the python -- version, I get the python version, so I assume it is installed. When I simply type python from the command line I get :
ImportError: No module name site
When I try python helloworld.py  I get the same error message.
I searched around in FAQ, I seems nobody has such problem.  I appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Python (Windows) - ImportError: No module named site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site)

Comment: have you tried running interpreter on a command line with -v option? I just ran into exactly the same "site import" error yesterday and with -v option got the exact stack trace of the offending package under site-packages that was causing the issue

Comment: Was it zipimport? How did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @user2672972: no for me it was something silly that I apparently did myself with repoze.who  (which I would like to call a package, but it doesn't have __init__.py files like normal packages do and when I added those to make IDE code completion happy, that's what broke the entire interpret in the same way as you are seeing)

Comment: Thanks Ewan : The answer is posted in Stackoverflow.com :Python (Windows) - ImportError: No module named site

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you uninstall the Python with Add or Remove Programs in control panel(link on how to do that below)

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307895

Then use the first download link on the python website or click the link below:

- [Python Download](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.msi)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However I did this two times before , I post the problem. I downloaded the same python.