# Python/IPython ImportError: no module named site

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-12.04, ipython, importerror

I had `python 2.7.3` and `ipython 1.2` up and running correctly on my `Linux` system (`ubuntu 12.04`) but was trying to install an updated version of matplotlab needed for coursework.

After running this code line in the terminal

```
user$ sudo easy_install -U distribute
user$ export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

now every time I try and run `python` or `ipython` I get the error message

```
ImportError: no module named site
```

how do I reverse/fix this problem?? I'm so lost. I looked at other similar issues, but no one else used `Linux` and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site

Answer (score 26):

TRY to unset your python path...

In Linux/Mac, you can use these commands:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
unset PYTHONHOME
```

Comment: After installing python with cygwin, I had this issue. An older version of python had been installed by a windows  program, and that was what cygwin was putting to the PYHONHOME variable. Once I unset as described above python within cygwin worked fine

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Worked for rhel7

Answer (score 18):

[`PYTHONHOME`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME)

> Change the location of the standard Python libraries. By default, the
>   libraries are searched in prefix/lib/pythonversion and
>   exec_prefix/lib/pythonversion, where prefix and exec_prefix are
>   installation-dependent directories, both defaulting to /usr/local.
>
> When PYTHONHOME is set to a single directory, its value replaces both
>   prefix and exec_prefix. To specify different values for these, set
>   PYTHONHOME to prefix:exec_prefix.

Try to clean up your `PYTHONHOME`:

```
user$ export PYTHONHOME=
```

As for installing matplotlib, I would recommend the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

(details [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html))

Comment: yes! that worked, thank you so much! The matplotlib version accessed using apt-get install is not the latest version...I tried using sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib but it's running a "Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1". I may just leave that be and try and solve it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Please accept the answer if that worked for you, this will also removed your question from the list of unanswered questions. Cheers

Comment: export PYTHONHOME=/usr/ 
did it for me

Answer (score 10):

you can `unset PYTHONHOME` to use the system default, or `export PYTHONHOME=/usr` to specify the prefix, to which Python will append '/lib/python2.7' (or whatever version it happens to be) to locate its libraries.

if you `export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7`, Python looks for libraries in the nonexistent folder `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7`.

and if you `export PYTHONHOME=`, you are telling Python to look for `lib` in the current working directory:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ PYTHONHOME= strace -estat64 /usr/bin/python
stat64("lib/python2.7/", 0xff870ee0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7", 0xff870ee0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat64("lib/python2.7/", 0xff873efc)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu", 0xff870ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7", 0xff870ee0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat64("lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu", 0xff873efc) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7/lib-tk", 0xff870ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7", 0xff870ee0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat64("lib/python2.7/lib-tk", 0xff873efc) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7/lib-old", 0xff870ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7", 0xff870ee0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat64("lib/python2.7/lib-old", 0xff873efc) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", 0xff870ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib/python2.7", 0xff870ee0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat64("lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", 0xff873efc) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
ImportError: No module named site
```