# Jython servlets on Tomcat-8/Java8

Tags: jython

I have sussessfully created servlets in Jython with Java7/Tomcat7
When I ran the same servlets on JDK8/Tomcat8 I have

```
    ImportError: No module named site

org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:328)
org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:842)
org.python.core.imp.load(imp.java:695)
org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:118)
org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:94)
org.python.util.PyServlet.createInterpreter(PyServlet.java:124)
org.python.util.PyServlet.reset(PyServlet.java:170)
org.python.util.PyServlet.init(PyServlet.java:90)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank you very much for your help

Regards

Comment: Did you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874407/python-ipython-importerror-no-module-named-site)?  Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968239/mac-python-import-error-no-module-named-site)?  Or maybe [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/285229/python-django-wsgi-apache-importerror-no-module-named-site)?

Comment: Which version of Jython are you using?

Comment: Hello David
I am using  Jython2.7b3

Comment: which version of *Jython*?

Comment: Version 2.7b3 on Netbeans

Comment: Would you try version 2.7b1 and see if the problem goes away?  I have a feeling it will.

Comment: Thanks Charles I will give you the feedback...

Comment: Great it works with 2.7b1 :-)

Comment: I have seen the very same problem with Java Webstart.  There is a lot of discussion concerning this problem at [bugs.jython.org](http://bugs.jython.org).

Comment: @DavidCharles Do you know if problem has been fixed in later version? Do you have bug number(s)?

Answer (score 0):

David Charles suggested me to use version 2.7b1
 and it works for me.