# Flask Server: ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to run a Flask application using a ubuntu 12.04 server with nginx and uWSGI however after starting the server, specifying the wsgi.ini file and then starting nginx, I try to access the page but I get a 502 bad gateway error with nginx. I know that it is an issue with the flask application and uWSGI. I checked the uWSGI logs and found this:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.1 (64bit) on [Thu Sep 17 19:38:03 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 17 September 2015 15:58:04
os: Linux-3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
nodename: ip-172-31-30-153
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/myapp
writing pidfile to /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7862
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:5000 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/myapp
ImportError: No module named site
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21874450/2961662) question's top answer but saw received the same error. If it is something to do with PYTHONHOME, I'm following [this guide](http://bathompso.com/blog/Flask-AWS-Setup/) and it states:

> The $PYTHONPATH variable seems to get unset randomly, and causes
>   errors for later steps. To avoid this, add the following line to the
>   top of your ~/.bashrc file:
>
> export
>   PYTHONPATH='/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat'

So what could be the issue? Is it PYTHONHOME or another factor affecting it? Thanks.

**Edit:**

My uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
home = /home/ubuntu/myapp
wsgi-file = %(home)/run.py
socket = 127.0.0.1:5000
callable = app
module = app
pythonpath = %(home)
daemonize = %(home)/myapp.log
pidfile = %(home)/myapp.pid
```

To run it, I use `uwsgi uwsgi.ini`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `pythonpath = %(home)` line?

Comment: @JeanJung I removed `pythonpath = %(home)` but there was no change.