# Cannot create project using Django

Tags: python, django

I've uninstalled 3.3 as I was working with Django and installed Python 2.7. But now I couldn't create project. I've un-installed Django and Python both and tried different versions but every time when I try to create a project with "django-admin.py startproject abc" it gives me some error:

```
  ImportError: No module named site
```

I've searched for a solution thoroughly tried different ways but this doesn't goes away. I can get into Python by typing in Python from command prompt so this isn't related to environment variable. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback. What version of Django are you using? Have you installed Django globally or are you using virtualenv? What OS are you using?

Comment: Maybe you are removed part of django libraries. Try reinstall it.

Comment: I've re-installed it several times. I am using Django globally as I am in learning process and am not using it as full time programmer. I am using 1.5. Thrice I've downloaded by removing complete Django installer package to re do from scratch. In vain. Full TraceBack is one liner comment that's posted in initial post.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site

Comment: I did tried that as that's why I mentioned in initial post that environment variable isn't the problem. However, I will try it again to ensure I haven't missed anything.

Comment: You can get into python from cmd doesn't mean PYTHONPATH variable is set. You can start python because it is in PATH. May be PYTHONPATH is not set.

Comment: From cmd, type `set PYTHONPATH` to see if it is set.

Comment: Tried everything but still the same error.

Comment: The only solution to this problem I can propose is to restore system to earlier point. It worked for me and would like to share this with all who are having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I resolved the same error message (ImportError: No module named site) that I got while trying this tutorial: https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html.

- Deactivate the virtualenv
- Install uWSGI system-wide (if not already installed system-wide)

sudo pip install uwsgi

- Edit the uwsgi.ini file. I commented out the line with the

home = /path/to/virtualenv

- Re-run the command: uWSGI --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini

Answer (score 0):

You should use **django-admin startproject PROJECT_NAME**