# unable to run matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

on 64bit win 7, I installed all of compatible versions of `setuptools`, `numpy`, `python-dateutil`, `pytz`, `pyparsing` and `six` in addition to `matplotlib`. I did this by downloading source into a folder, and installing from source ... for example,

```
python setup.py install
```

finally, I installed python matplotlib by,

```
cd matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

I tested `matplotlib` by running python from my windows powershell, and typing `import pylab` I got error:

> ImportError: error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source ...

I found a stackoverflow question that addressed this, leading answer was to change working directory from the directory where numpy lives.

I changed the working directory to another folder in my drive, again ran python from my interpreter, typed `import pylab` and received this error:

> ImportError: NO module named numpy"

I am now at a loss. It either refuses to import `numpy`, or says it doesn't exist? But it knew it existed earlier?

Ive been looking for a solution for more than three hours now, am stumped. Apologies in advance if this question seems too noob.

finally, I am open to trying a different module if it would be easier. I only want to plot some data.

Comment: Looks like you need to set your `PYTHONPATH`. Have you tried that? Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5687052/588071) will help.

Comment: Maybe you have a good reason for it, but using a pre compiled  package like anaconda python makes your life considerably easier.