# python "No module named site"

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, python-module

So I have searched this question before, and it's been answered satisfactorily for other users on stackoverflow ([Python (Windows) - ImportError: No module named site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site)).  stackoverflow says I should avoid asking a question in an answer on that page, and I do not have enough reputation to comment.

So here is the issue (repeated from other question): when I run python, I get the error "ImportError: No module named site"

I installed it as a different user, but with the option to install for all users.  That account is privileged (administrators), and when I run python it works just fine.  I'm setting up this computer to run a small interface for other users, so want it to run under a normal account that multiple people will have the password for.

This is a Windows 7 box; I completely removed ALL versions of python and installed the latest Python 2.7 (currently 12, as I write this) and PyQt4.

The application runs as a user with admin rights, but doesn't run for the created limited account.

I've reduced the command file to the following:

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\lib
set PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PATH%
python
pause
```

I've also tried using quotes around the paths.  It is correct - if I run this as the user that installed python, it works.  Obviously the issue is not paths or environment variables.

Comment: Why are you setting PYTHONPATH like that?

Comment: As directed by the answers for the same question that I gave the link to in the first paragraph - I did not do that initially, but wanted to show I followed the answers given when the question was asked previously.  It definitely should not be necessary, I know that.  I don't set any environment variables if I'm running as the user with admin privileges that installed python, it just works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i have come up with my search :

**Possible causes**
Squish source build without Python

This typically occurs with Squish source builds that have Python configured.

**Solution:**

Either set the environment variable PYTHONHOME to the path of the Python libraries, or add an entry similar to this:

```
Scripting/PythonHome = "C:\\Python26"
```

in the file SQUISHDIR/etc/paths.ini. Of course, you must put the correct path for your Python installation there. (Note that Squish only supports Python versions 2.4-2.7.)

**Python related environment variables**

This problem can also occur if the PYTHONHOME variable points to a different Python installation than the one used by Squish.

**Solution:**

Unset the PYTHONHOME environment variable before starting the Squish IDE (or the squishserver).

this kind of works for me, I hope the same happens to you to :D

[source](https://kb.froglogic.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2457937)

Comment: I don't use squish.