# Qt calling python using QProcess

Tags: python, c++, qt

I'm trying to launch a python script from a QT project using QProcess and It appears I keep getting an error saying

**Error:**

```
Debugging starts
Python error: "ImportError: No module named site\r\n"  
Python result= ""
Debugging has finished
```

However I've broken this down to such a simple project. I am completely dumb-founded on why this is happening. I've search for a few hours here online and found some links on SO suggesting i set env paths, which didn't help at either. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are my project files and specs:

- **Local Python Install**: 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
- **Computer**: Windows 7 Pro
- **Qt Creator 4.2**: Building with Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MinGW 32 Bit

---

**pythonTest.py**: This is the python file that the QT project should be calling

```
print('hello world')
```

**mainwindow.cpp**: I simply created a new project add here is the mainwindow.cpp code

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    QString pythonPath = "C:/Python27/python.exe";
    QString pythonScript = "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/pythonTest.py";

    params << pythonScript;
    p.start(pythonPath, params);
    p.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString p_stdout = p.readAll();
    QString p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();
    if(!p_stderr.isEmpty())
       qDebug()<<"Python error:"<<p_stderr;
    qDebug()<<"Python result="<<p_stdout;
}
```

**UPDATE (ekhumoro SOLUTION)**

```
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("PYTHONPATH", "C:\\Python27\\Lib");
env.insert("PYTHONHOME", "C:\\Python27");
p.setProcessEnvironment(env);
```

Comment: What if you use a windows path for script location? `QString pythonScript = "C:\\Users\\Martini\\Desktop\\trash\\pythonTest.py";`

Comment: didn't work either, same error

Comment: What about this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site

Comment: already tried that, didn't help either

Comment: @JokerMartini. This obviously **must** be a problem with python envars - nothing else makes sense (given that import error). I suggest you try  using [setProcessEnvironment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment) to set `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Ok let me try that. I'll let you know. I'll be home in 30 mins

Comment: that fixed it!!!! Thank you so much