# Python based converted exe running in other systems

Tags: python-3.x, gis, pyinstaller, gdal, osgeo

I developed some scripts using python3 for GIS related activities using python osgeo, ogr,gdal, module. I converted my script.py to exe using pyinstaller. The converted exe is working on my system well but i f run the same exe othe systems its giving error like nomodule named gdal. I ran the exe with all dll files which developed while in process of py to exe conversion. Please help me?[image]

Comment: Have a look at this discussion, could be related to the python path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site

Comment: no it's  not a path issue program is working fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not include all of your dependencies after all (e.g. `_gdal` module is missing as the error says). The solution is to include all dependent DLL modules (including transitive dependencies - which I suspect you missed here).