# Set $PYTHONHOME and $PYTHONPATH, but still cannot run unit tests

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, virtualenv

I'm using Django and Python 3.7 on Mac High Sierra.  I'm having an issue when trying to run my unit tests.  Following teh advice here -- [Python (Windows) - ImportError: No module named site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site) , I set my $PYTHONHOME and $PYTHONPATH

```
localhost:mainpage_project davea$ echo $PYTHONHOME
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7
localhost:mainpage_project davea$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/bin/python
localhost:mainpage_project davea$
```

Not sure why I need to do this since I'm using a virtual environment.  Nonetheless, when I run the tests, I get

```
localhost:mainpage_project davea$ ./manage.py test
ImportError: No module named site
```

I'm at a loss for other variables I need to set in order to proceed.

Comment: Your `$PYTHONPATH` is wrong. It must be set to a **library** directory, not to a binary. Something like `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7`. In a virtualenv you don't need `PYTHONPATH` at all.